# COMAdminCatalogCollection.Populate throws error C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, com+, catalog

I am using the COMAdminCatalog API for .net. I am currently getting certain properties of COM+ applications and components from an array of servers remotely. For the most part, my process doesn't have a problem retrieving this data. However, a few of the COM+ application's components will not populate and throws the following exception:

Error Message: Errors occurred accessing one or more objects - the ErrorInfo collection may have more detail (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80110401)
I try getting the ErrorInfo collection, but no errorInfo objects are returned, so that doesn't help me in trouble shooting.
Here is the documentation: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686530(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is the method I am using to try to populate a component collection. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
private static bool TryPopulateComponent(COMAdminCatalogCollection cOMAdminCatalogComponentCollection,
            COMAdminCatalogObject application = null, COMAdminCatalogObject component = null, string serverName = null)
        {
            try
            {
                cOMAdminCatalogComponentCollection.Populate();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                COMAdminCatalogCollection errorInfos = cOMAdminCatalogComponentCollection.GetCollection("ErrorInfo", varObjectKey: application.Key);
                errorInfos.Populate();
                foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject errorInfo in errorInfos)
                {
                    var errorCode = errorInfo.Value["ErrorCode"];
                    var majorRef = errorInfo.Value["MajorRef"];
                    var minorRef = errorInfo.Value["MinorRef"];
                    var name = errorInfo.Value["Name"]; 
                }

                COMException comException = new COMException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException,
                    application, component, serverName);
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not populate {component?.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                LogTools.LogError(comException);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: struggling through this also as we speak. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Yes, I went into Component Services on the machine I was logging information from that was giving me an error, I clicked on the application that threw the error, clicked on the "components" node to expand the components, and it gave me a pop up with a table that had the component name, and the reason for the error. for me it was several components that could not be found in the registry, but were still in the COM+ Application if that makes sense, once we removed these components from COM+ application, the issue was resolved. I hope this helps you, as I remember this was a true pain.

Comment: hey thanks for the followup. My issue here was slightly different, turned out to my component dll required `msvcr71.dll` in the same folder in order for each component to be detected properly within that assembly.

Comment: Glad you found an answer. The joys of programming.